# How to bake material texures from a high poly character to a lower poly, retoplogized version of the character

Tags: texturing, materials, baking

After having baked normals from a high poly version of a character to a low poly version, I am now wanting to bake the material texture from the high poly character to the low poly character. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hello, have you followed some tutorials on this topic and why doesn't it work? You need to select the high-poly, shift select the low-poly, choose Diffuse as Bake Type, disable Influence >Contributions > Direct and Indirect